# Removing all lines containing a specific text between square brackets

Tags: sed, grep

I'm stacking in manipulating some data.
I want to remove every line that contain a specific text between [ ]
My file is like the following:

```
cat file1 

today_is_a_new_day#1 12123 12356 [today is a new day]
today_is_a_new_day#2 14531 12456 [today is a new day]
today_is_a_new_day#3 12345 12456 [today is a new day]
tommorow_will_be_a_new_day#1 2342 34124 [tommorow will be a new day]
tommorow_will_be_a_new_day#2 2342 34144 [tommorow will be a new day]
today_is_a_new_day#4 12343 12452 [today is a new day]
today_is_a_new_day#5 12348 12451 [today is a new day]
tommorow_will_be_a_new_day#3 2342 34144 [today is a new day]
```

I want to obtain

```
tommorow_will_be_a_new_day#1 2342 34124 [tommorow will be a new day]
tommorow_will_be_a_new_day#2 2342 34144 [tommorow will be a new day]
```

I tried the following:

```
egrep  -ve "\[today" -e is -e a -e new -e "day]" file1 

echo [today is a new day] >file2
cat file1 |grep -vwf- file2
```

The only way I found working was :

```
sed 's/today_is_a_new_day/temp/'g file1| grep -vi today |sed 's/temp/today_is_a_new_day/'g >desired_output.txt
```

Is any way to make it more simply?

Comment: `I want to remove everything containing a specific text between [ ]` You nowhere do that. You want to _filter lines_, not remove text between `[]`. Och, by "remove everything", you meant "remove lines". Could you explain your code? Why do you do `'s/today_is_a_new_day/temp/'`?

Comment: `grep -Fv '[today is a new day]' file1 > file2`?

Comment: @kimilCum... Im so sorry. I didnt express what I want well. I will re-write my title.

Comment: `grep -v "\[today is a new day]" today.txt` is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like you want:

```
grep -Fv '[today is a new day]' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed variant

```
$ sed '/\[tommorow will be a new day\]/d' file 
today_is_a_new_day#1 12123 12356 [today is a new day]
today_is_a_new_day#2 14531 12456 [today is a new day]
today_is_a_new_day#3 12345 12456 [today is a new day]
today_is_a_new_day#4 12343 12452 [today is a new day]
today_is_a_new_day#5 12348 12451 [today is a new day]
tommorow_will_be_a_new_day#3 2342 34144 [today is a new day]
```

Answer (score 1):

The sed way: Remove all the line which contain  `sed '/^.*\[today .*day\].*$/d' file1 > file2`. P/s: Why dont you just use cat and grep what you want only

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for answering me. I tested your command and worked too!!!  When I used the grep after the cat  if use the target word "tommorow" it prints the tommorow_will_be_a_new_day#3 2342 34144 [today is a new day] which includes the word "today" . As im bash newbie I tried to target in specific words inside the square brackets. The only way to handle it was by  sed 's/today_is_a_new_day/temp/'g file1| grep -vi today |sed 's/temp/today_is_a_new_day/'g >desired_output.txt  which is very long command :-(

Comment: I mean this: ```cat file1 | grep "tommorow will be a new day"
tommorow_will_be_a_new_day#1 2342 34124 [tommorow will be a new day]
tommorow_will_be_a_new_day#2 2342 34144 [tommorow will be a new day]```

Comment: ohh i see... you are absolutely correct... I thought a bit complicated... Thank you very much for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

If interested in awk; this will work for you.

```
awk '!/\[today is a new day\]/' inputfile
```

Comment: I like the "awk" approach.... Thank you so much for the post.